# Caching does not exist in namespace Microsoft.Extensions

Tags: .net, caching, dependency-injection, nuget, azure-functions

I am moving some logic from a micro service to a azure function.

Things are going pretty smoothly, however I have run into a dependency issue. I had some caching features in the micro service that I would like to keep in the azure function, however the function project will not build because it cannot resolve `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` namespace.

I installed `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` via nuget in the new function project so that I could use DI in this function app. I think this is the reason why `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching` is no longer resolving.

The error is the common: `The type or namespace 'Caching' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions'`

Shouldn't they both be exposed under Microsoft.Extensions namespace?
Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Some code samples.

Function Code:
(DI setup is almost exactly [this](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-dependency-injection/))

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using PI.Warehouses.API.Repositories;
using ESPIWarehouseFunction.Injection;

namespace ESPIWarehouseFunction
{
    public static class WarehouseFunctions
    {

        [FunctionName("GetAll")]
        public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, 
            TraceWriter log, [Inject(typeof(IWarehouseStateRepository))]IWarehouseStateRepository repoW)
        {
            log.Info("GetAll Function is processing a request");
            var warehouses = repoW.GetAllWarehouses();
            return warehouses != null ? 
                (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(warehouses) :
                new BadRequestObjectResult("Something went wrong with this request");
        }
    }
}
```

One of many code pieces that uses the cache:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using MediatR;
using PI.Warehouses.Domain.Aggregate.Commands;
using PI.Warehouses.Domain.Aggregate.Events;
using PI.Warehouses.Domain.Model;
using PI.Warehouses.API.Repositories;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PI.Warehouses.Domain.Aggregate.Exceptions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace PI.Warehouses.API.Application.Handlers.Commands
{
    public class AddMaterialHandler : IRequestHandler<AddMaterialCommand, EventList>
    {
        private readonly IEventRepository _repoEvents;
        private readonly IWarehouseStateRepository _repoWarehouse;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private IMemoryCache _cache;
        private EventList _eventsCreated;

        public AddMaterialHandler(IEventRepository repoE, IWarehouseStateRepository repoW, IMediator mediator, IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _repoEvents = repoE;
            _repoWarehouse = repoW;
            _mediator = mediator;
            _cache = cache;
            _eventsCreated = new EventList();
        }

            // some setups stuffs ...

            WarehouseState state;
            if (!_cache.TryGetValue(cmd.WarehouseId, out WarehouseState cachedState))
                state = await _repoWarehouse.GetWarehouseState(cmd.WarehouseId);
            else
                state = new WarehouseState(cachedState);


            // Rest of this handler
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide how your code looks like?

Comment: It spans across many files that use IMemoryCache. But essentially is just the ‘using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory’ statements that are the root of the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a clean function and installed both packages, I used interfaces from both of them(so I have both usings) and all seems to work correctly:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }

        public class MyCache : IMemoryCache
        {
            public void Dispose()
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Remove(object key)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public class ServicesCollection : IServiceCollection
        {
            public IEnumerator<ServiceDescriptor> GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }

            public void Add(ServiceDescriptor item)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Clear()
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool Contains(ServiceDescriptor item)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void CopyTo(ServiceDescriptor[] array, int arrayIndex)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool Remove(ServiceDescriptor item)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public int Count { get; }
            public bool IsReadOnly { get; }
            public int IndexOf(ServiceDescriptor item)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void Insert(int index, ServiceDescriptor item)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public void RemoveAt(int index)
            {
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }

            public ServiceDescriptor this[int index]
            {
                get => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
                set => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without a sample from your code it will be hard to diagnose the real issue.

EDIT: 
Here is my `.csproj` for a project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.14" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Added some code snippets for you. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @Lamar - what are the versions of both packages?

Comment: 2.1.1 - M.E.DI, not sure about caching though. Does microsoft.extension come from Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions? If so then 1.0.6. @kamil-mrzyglod

Comment: would you mind telling me what package you installed to be able to use microsoft.extension.caching in the function project. It was available to me by default in my last project.